# Assign query result to variable while passing table name as parameter in azure synapse stored procedure

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Passing table name as parameter to Azure Synapse stored procedure and assign the query(use the passed parameter in SQL) result to variable.

Sample code below:

```
CREATE PROC [TEST].[DEMO_PROC] @TableName [VARCHAR](1000) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count_variable INT;
    SELECT @count_variable=count(1) FROM @TableName
    PRINT @count_variable
END
```

ERROR: Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Parse error at line: 39, column: 42: Incorrect syntax near '@TableName'.

I get an error message saying TableName cannot be assigned as a parameter, If I give a hardcoded table name instead of variable it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL. Build the statement as a variable, concatenating the @TableName as appropriate, then pass the variable to EXEC:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID(@TableName) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @TableName;
    EXEC(@sql)
END
```

Comment: But how to assign the result of dynamic query to a variable in azure synapse stored procedure. for ex in my case @count_variable should have the count result of the dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

It works by using sp_executesql:
Below is the changed SP which is working.

```
CREATE PROC [TEST].[DEMO_PROC] @TableName VARCHAR AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);  
DECLARE @count_variable INT;

SET @SQLString = 'SELECT @count_variable = count(1)   FROM '+@TableName ;  
SET @ParmDefinition = '@count_variable INT OUTPUT';  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,  @count_variable=@count_variable OUTPUT;  

PRINT @count_variable;

END
```